# Matlab: selecting non-consecutive matrix columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I've got a 28 x 28 x 1 x 10000 matrix called `data` and a 1 x 10000 vector called `labels`, which consists of a bunch of integers from 0 - 9. What I'd really like to do is split the `data` matrix into 10 smaller matrices, corresponding to the `label` values.

Is there any way to do this other than a for loop?

Comment: Did you mean that labels has the size of 10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab allows slice indexing.  For example:

```
data(:,:,:,1:1000)
```

I can't see how you're getting "non-consecutive".  There's a hint there of selecting on the label, but the dimensions don't match.  If they did:

```
data(:,:,:,label == 1)
```

or

```
data(:,:,:,find(label == 1))
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo, there are 10000 labels. In terms of slices, i'd need to be able to say 1:3 but also 4 and then also 7:10 and so on. I'll give the conditional a try though